# Metadata is not being added when explicitly defined

Tags: metadata

when running the below command

```
ffmpeg -i '.\input - s01e01.mp4' -metadata iTunEXTC="mpaa|TV-Y|300|BecasueReasons" '.\output - s01e01.mp4'
```

the metadata field is not added.

Comment: An older post, but a comment on [this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/1288741/) says that ffmpeg cannot edit that tag.  It gives a few alternative programs to change it.